# Passing object of a class to method of another class

Tags: java

I have a class named employee and it has one private field which is ArrayList named empList. I have another class Database and it has method named insert(). This insert() method takes ArrayList empList as an arguement. How to pass this empList to the insert().

Comment: please share your code

Comment: there is a site called *google.com* which always adds to your knowledge....keep *stackoverflow.com* as last resort!!!

Answer (score 1):

just pass the argument as you would pas any other argument.

`insert(empList)`

and declare insert as `insert(ArrayList<Type> empList)`

Answer (score 1):

If the insert method is static in the class Database then you could simply pass like this
Database.insert(empList); 
or you can create an object and pass like this.
Database db = new Database()
db.insert(empList);

Answer (score 1):

You have to construct an object of the type of the first class (which you are not mentioning) inside `Database`.

```
class Database{

void insert(ArrayList lst){
.....//your business  logic
}

void invokeInsert(){
YourClass x = new YourClass();
insert(x.getList());
}

class YourClass{
private ArrayList list;

public ArrayList getList(){
return list;
}
}
```